# Preventing last cell row being checked after clicking first and vice versa & adding/removing selected rows to array

Tags: swift, uitableview, cell, didselectrowatindexpath

Im using a tableview to display an array of strings. When I click on a particular row, I want it to be highlighted with a checkmark. When I deselect a row, I want the checkmark to be removed. When I press a button, I want the rows that are currently highlighted to be passed out in an array(newFruitList).

My problem is that when I click the first row, the last is highlighted. When I uncheck the first row, the last is unchecked, as if they are the same cell?

How do I overcome this?

Also, the way I am adding and removing from my new array, is this the correct way to go about doing this?
Thanks

My Code:

```
class BookingViewController: UIViewController, ARSKViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

    let fruits = ["Apples", "Oranges", "Grapes", "Watermelon", "Peaches"]
    var newFruitList:[String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.table.dataSource = self
        self.table.delegate = self
        self.table.allowsMultipleSelection = true

}

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return fruits.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")
        if cell == nil{
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        }

        cell?.textLabel?.text = fruits[indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        newFruitList.append(fruits[indexPath.row])
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark

        }

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let index = newFruitList.index(of: fruits[indexPath.row]) {
            newFruitList.remove(at: index)
        }
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            cell.accessoryType = .none
        }

    }

    @IBAction func bookButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

//testing purposes
        for i in stride(from: 0, to: newFruitList.count, by: 1){
           print(newFruitList[i])
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

They are probably the same cell because you use `dequeueReusableCell` and it reuses old cells.

use:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
    }
```

To reset the cell and it should be fine.

As for the save and send mission. Create an pre-indexed array that you can populate.

```
var selected: [Bool] = []
var fruits: [Fruit] = [] {
     didSet {
        selected = Array(repeating: false, count: fruits.count)
     }
}
```

And in your didSelectItemAt you do:

`selected[indexPath.item] = !selected[indexPath.item]`

Comment: so in my  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell method would I just do cell.prepareForReuse after declaring the cell var?

Comment: Ah, right, you are not using custom cells? Then directly when initiating the cell set `cell.accessoryType = .none`

Answer (score 0):

`UITableView` reuses the cell that is already present and hence you will see that duplicate check mark, so to solve this issue you need to clear the cell states while loading cell. for that you can create a model with property to track the states of your selected cells

So your fruit model must be like below

```
class Fruit{
    var name:String
    var isSelected:Bool
    init(name:String){
        isSelected = false
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

Then you will have table view populated with `Fruit` list

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")
        if cell == nil{
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        }
       let model = fruits[indexPath.row]
       cell?.textLabel?.text = model.name
       if(model.isSelected){
           cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
       }
       else{
          cell.accessoryType = .none
       }

        return cell!

}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        newFruitList.append(fruits[indexPath.row])

        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
            var model = fruits[indexPath.row]
            model.isSelected = true
        }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let index = newFruitList.index(of: fruits[indexPath.row]) {
            newFruitList.remove(at: index)
        }
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            cell.accessoryType = .none
            var model = fruits[indexPath.row]
            model.isSelected = false
        }

    }
```

Comment: Models should be created as structs and should never contain `var` but `let`

Comment: structs are value type's, so for this scenario it won't update the model in list when changing the state, also let are constants and won't change the value, hence var is used

Comment: the line if let model = causes errors? Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'BookingViewController.Contact'

Comment: that is for safely unwrapping optionals, so if your model is not optional you can skip that unwrapping part and use normal let or var statement there

Comment: Cannot invoke 'index' with an argument list of type '(of: Fruit)' ??

Comment: my fruit arrays declared like this :     var fruits:[Fruit] = [Fruit(name: "Appler"),Fruit(name: "Orange")]
    var newFruitList:[Fruit] = []

Comment: We may continue this discussion here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/166865/preventing-last-cell-row-being-checked-after-clicking-first-and-vice-versa-addi?tab=conversations